# xinha editor enabiling GetHtml

Tags: php, editor, addition, edit

Does anyone know how to enable GetHtml in xinha editor?

I tried to implement this:

> > GetHtml is a replacement for the getHTML() function in htmlarea.js. It
> >     offers several improvements over the original, including:
>
> - Produces valid XHTML code
> - Formats code in HTML view in indented, readable format.
> - Much faster than HTMLArea.getHTML()
> - Eliminates many hacks to accomodate browser quirks
> - Returns correct code for Flash objects and scripts
> - Preserves formatting inside script and pre tags
> - You can enable this by setting xinha_config.getHtmlMethod to    "TransformInnerHTML"

But I didn't understand very well and this is my attempt:

```
var xinha_plugins =
[
 'GetHtml','ExtendedFileManager','Linker','InsertSmiley'
];
```

I just added the plug-in to the plug-ins library above(like my code), but the plug-ins didn't work! I need to insert flash in xinha editor.